# Getting two JSON´s from the same URL in Swift

Tags: json, swift

I need to compare data from two diferente dates and I'm trying to get two Jsons with two dates, from the same URL request. What I did is basically I repeated the same Json request with slightly diferente names. While its giving me a "index out range" and also pretty sure that this is not how its suppose to be done. Its too much code and Im going to need some more data. Can you please tell how its supposed to be done or direct me to some tutorial since I couldn't google anything. This is my code:

```
    let parameters = "{\n\t\"local\": \"MainPlace\",\n\t\"date\": \"\(today)\",\n\t\"access_token\": \"\(token)\"\n}"

    let postData = parameters.data(using: .utf8)

    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://someurl")!,timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = postData

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data else {
            print(error!)
            return
        }

        print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)

        let decoder = JSONDecoder()

        do {
            let jsonPetitions = try decoder.decode(RootRequest.self, from: data)
            self.locales = jsonPetitions.results

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                        jsonYesterday()
                                    }


        } catch {
            print(error)

        }
    }
    task.resume()

    func jsonYesterday(){
        // yesterday


               let parametersI = "{\n\t\"local\": \"MainPlace\",\n\t\"date\": \"\(yesterday)\",\n\t\"access_token\": \"\(token)\"\n}"

               let postDataI = parametersI.data(using: .utf8)

               var requestI = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://someurl")!,timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)
               requestI.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

               requestI.httpMethod = "POST"
               requestI.httpBody = postDataI

               let taskI = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: requestI) { dataI, response, error in
                   guard let dataI = dataI else {
                       print(error!)
                       return
                   }
                   print(String(data: dataI, encoding: .utf8)!)

                   let decoderI = JSONDecoder()

                   do {
                       let jsonPetitionsI = try decoderI.decode(RootRequest.self, from: dataI)
                    self.yesterdayStruct = jsonPetitionsI.results
                       yesterdaysResults = self.yesterdayStruct.count
                       DispatchQueue.main.async {
                           self.tableView.reloadData()
                       }

                   } catch {
                       print(error)

                   }
               }
               taskI.resume()

    }
```

Comment: _"...tell how its supposed to be done..."_, sorry but how what is supposed to be done? What are you trying to do and what is your question?

Comment: I dont understand whats the proper way of getting múltiple Json requests at the same time, basically.

Comment: If you need to make 2 independent concurrent requests, see if this article helps you get there: https://medium.com/@novinfard/syncing-multiple-asynchronous-tasks-in-swift-4fd49453b739

Comment: Very good article. I manage to make it work. Thank you so much